# Retracted flag was changed to disputed?

Tags: support, bug, flags, disputed-flags, retracted-flags

I flagged [this question<sup>(10K link)</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39554010/another-domain-use-my-complete-site-content) as spam but after further digging, I retracted my spam flag <sup>([Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/))</sup>.

And at first, the flag showed as "retracted" on my `stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/...` page.

But rechecking today, the retracted flag has been changed to disputed.  I know this because I have a userscript that tracks flag change status.  This is the current screen shot:

[image: Unretracted flag!]

Note how that one  post jumped from the "R" column to the "Ds" column in the summary table.

What's going on here?
This sure looks like a bug.  Can retracted flags also be declined or expired?

Comment: I had a similar experience: Retracted a rude/abusive flag, but it was listed as disputed later. Though could have been a race condition, as it looked like the flags on [the post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333333/559745) got handled by a mod at the same time..

Comment: What is that fanciful table userscript that shows the flag listing like this?

Comment: @Magisch, It's a private userscript.  I'll clean up and publish a version of it in the next few days.

Comment: @BrockAdams That'd be great :D

Comment: @BrockAdams did you publish the US till now? If so, could you give a link?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ, Okay, you can find it at http://stackapps.com/questions/7057/flagging-assistant-tweaks-for-frequent-flaggers .  Beware that my internal version is different, so I might have introduced or missed some bugs with the public version.

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks! I'll report any bugs on GH if I find any.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can only ever happen with spam/offensive flags. When a moderator uses the "clear all spam/offensive flags" tool on a post, it simply changes *all* spam/offensive flags (both handled and pending) on the post to disputed, regardless of what status they previously had.

This tool is meant to clear all the helpful flags off the post to remove any penalties it might have caused and prevent it being used as a review audit, but sometimes gets used to "kindly" dismiss flags on borderline posts instead of declining them. It is lazily implemented since changing the declined and [newly added] retracted flags to disputed causes absolutely no harm and there's no reason to make the logic more complicated just to prevent that.

Comment: So, you are saying that you know that retracted flags get changed to disputed in this scenario? (We disagree about the harm, admittedly minor, but still.)

Comment: Yes, that is how the tool works. It simply looks for all spam/offensive flags and sets them to disputed.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Still annoying in the "retracted" case.  I want my "backsies", darn it!

Comment: Note that this answer would imply that "Expired" flags got changed to "Disputed" too.  Has anyone seen that?  (I'm guessing that expired flags are rare on SO, though.)

Comment: If a spam/offensive flag managed to expire on its own, it's incredibly unlikely the post would ever be in a situation where moderators would opt to manually clear them all off the post. But yes, they would be changed too if that ever happened.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the behavior is intentional when it comes to also updating retracted flags to disputed in this manner. More likely that Michael didn't know this happened and I didn't think about it much. Not sure off-hand if "fixing" this is worth it, but current behavior does break expectations in ways that resetting active/handled/expired flags doesn't IMO, so it at least merits some investigation.